# Outlook 2016 - Crashing on Add-in dialog close

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, add-in, office-js, outlook-2016

I'm working on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and we've been encountering an issue with Outlook 2016 crashing on dialog close, intermittently.  For further context, we’ve noticed this occurs on Version 1807, Build 10325.20082.

When we try to close the dialog, the CPU usage on Outlook 2016 goes up significantly, crashing Outlook 2016 after the dialog is closed.  We have debugged this but aren’t able to see any error lines on the console.  This issue with Outlook 2016 crashing also seems to also be affecting other add-ons (Dropbox, Boomerang and Salesforce) in production.

We have noticed this bug is prevalent in the current version (Version 1807, Build 10325.20082).  It wasn’t a problem on the prior versions from a few weeks ago.

**Code Sample:**

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogURL, {
         height: 60,
         width: 33,
         displayInIframe: true,
       }, dialogCallback.bind(self, handleDialogMessage));   

let handleDialogMessage = function(dialog, args) { 
        dialog.close(); 
        event.completed(); // event = argument for manifest button click 
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why would this not be reported to Micro$oft ???

Comment: When you say "crash" do you mean that outlook.exe shuts down, or do you mean it is unresponsive to clicks?

Comment: Outlook becomes unresponsive to clicks, and we have to force quit it from Task Manager.

Comment: We repro'ed something similar, and verify that it has been fixed in the next release of the C2R update. 16.0.10730.XXXXXX. I do not have an eta on this release, but it should be in the next few weeks.

A similar fix for the issue we saw was backported to 16.10325.20118. This build has already started to roll out to customers, which may have also fixed the same issue.

Comment: We confirmed on our end that 16.0.10325.20118 seems to have fixed the issue. If you continue to see this bug in versions later than that, please update us.